# Unable to load C Project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

When i try to load my C project in VS 2015,i got this error :

"Project cannot be loaded because installation components are missing : please install visual c++ 2015 tools for Windows Desktop".

Does somebody know how can i fix it without reinstalling VS2015 ?

Comment: Hope this helps - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/24/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers.aspx

Comment: Thank you.Howerver the only way it worked for me was to desinstall and reinstall it . Kind of time consuming, but it'll force me to read the conditions next time !

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To not reinstall Visual Studio which is time consuming, you need to go to **File** >> **New** >> **Project** and then choose Visual C++ folder.
There you will find your unavailable project that is saying

> Install visual C++ 2015 tools for Windows Desktop

So just click on it and start installing the needed components. After the installation has completed, you'll be able to start and write C++ applications for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Thanks for nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the button doesn't show up (it only shows in the log), go to File -> New Project. Under Templates -> Visual C++ , it will show "Install Visual 2015 C++ Tools For Windows Desktop" as if it's one of the possible project templates. That'll show the install prompt.